# c# error cant understand what i should do to solve it

Tags: c#, boolean

hi i have this code(and i get the ERROR  that i must declare a body because it is not not marked abstract,extern or partial...by the way i couldnt get it to post it here but right over the public partial class Form1 : Form  i also have written bool play1 = true;bool play2 = false; int x=1;int o=10;  )when i click on it it goes up to that area that i marked with fat letters
could someone please show me what is wrong and how to solve it step by step

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{                
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        værdier();
        int[] status = new int[9];
        zeihne();
    }

    private string[] status; 

    private void value()      
    { 
        int[] status = new int[9];
        zeihne();        
    }

    private void zeihne()        
    {  
        button1.Text = status[0];
        button2.Text = status[1];
        button3.Text = status[2];
        button4.Text = status[3];
        button5.Text = status[4];
        button6.Text = status[5]; 
        button7.Text = status[6];
        button8.Text = status[7];
        button9.Text = status[8];
    }


   //      private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    **private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e);**

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (play1 == true)
        {
            play1 = true;
            button1.Text = "X";
            play1 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            play2 = true;
            button1.Text = "O";
            play2 = false;
            play1 = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the method body for

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

That's an abstract method and they are only allowed on abstract classes

Something like this would do the trick

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Or you can just get rid of the method if you don't plan to have any code on it.

**EDIT**

Something else that looks weird on your code is

```
//      private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
```

What are you trying to do? Two options:

```
// Option1: All the method commented
*/private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}*/

// Option2: Nothing commented
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
```

Comment: @Hwoarang H: added more comments to my answer

Comment: i just got that error to go away. but for the option 1 and 2 u gave me that one with label1_click just happened by accident because i clicked on a label instead of a box to go into the code once..and i dont know if i can just erase it.

Comment: but now i get some warnings instead telling me that x is issigned to but never used, o is assigned to but never used and status is assigned to but never used...how do i solve it please?

Answer (score -1):

Hello Hwoarang H i tryed your code in my form and its working fine. You have to just follow step.

You have difine your method like this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

This is not right way to define method like this.You must declare like bellow

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { }
```

Now remove your lable click event and brackets

```
//      private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
//{


//}
```

Now you got warning like x is issigned to but never used, o is assigned to but never used and status is assigned to but never used.No warry about that bcos you assign x and o as integer and used as string so this warning is come,i dont know whats your logic but if you want to remove this warning than use this int x,and o.Also play2 is never used so put condition like bellow

```
 if (play1 == true)
            {

                btnSendNotification.Text = "x";
                play1 = false;
            }
            else if(play2==true)
            {

                btnSendNotification.Text = "o";
                play2 = false;
                play1 = true;
            }
```

Hope this is help you if not get solution than comment me.